# DFS Migration from 2003 R2 to 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, migration, dfs, windows-server-2003-r2

In our environment we have 6 domain controllers. 2 of them are running 2003 R2 and we are in the process of decommissioning them. These servers are hosting our single namespace for \domain.com\DFS. We have no replication in place and these servers are not hosting any of the files that are utilized by DFS. We wish to migrate these settings to our 2 newer servers using 2008 R2. The goal is to have only 4 DCs after we are done, 2 of them having DFS.

I have used dfsutil to export the namespace into a txt file, and changed the target servers to the new machines. I'm not sure if it's okay to simply import this into the new servers after DFS has been added to their roles, or if I should add the DFS role to them then add the server names to the old DFS 'namespace servers' box and hope that they replicate the settings to the new ones. Does it even work that way?

What would be the proper process for the migration of these settings to the newer servers?

Thanks for any help,

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

If you add the 2008 servers to the list of namespace servers for your DFS root, they'll work just fine. However, you will miss out on some of the features of the 2008 DFS namespace root.

Also see:

Manual upgrade DFS namespace from 2000 -> 2008
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753875.aspx